# How do people with a flip phone comply with Australia's new law?

Tags: australia, phone

Recently Australia passed regulations requiring some citizens to download an app to their phones and occasionally send geotracked selfies to the government to confirm their location.

How would someone who only has a flip phone and for whatever reason can't afford to upgrade to a smartphone comply with the law?

Comment: Which law is this? Can you provide a citation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### They don’t get to quarantine at home

If they are unable or unwilling to comply with the law for whatever reason, they cannot use the new at-home quarantine and will have to stay (and pay for) hotel quarantine. Since that costs $3,000+ a $700 smart phone looks like a good investment.

Or, they can just stay out of Australia and avoid quarantine entirely.